# country_select gem wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I put this in my gemfile

`gem 'country_select'`

I run bundle install

I put this in my form

`= f.country_select(:country, priority_countries: ["US"])`

Then when I restart the server and load the page I get the following error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):`

Rails 5.2

here is the entire form:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|

    .row
      .col.s12      
        = devise_error_messages!

    .row
      .input-field.col.s12
        = f.text_field :city
        = f.label :city

    .row
      .input-field.col.s12
        = f.label :country  
        %br
        = f.country_select(:country, priority_countries: ["US"])
```

This is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
    20:           .input-field.col.s12
    21:             = f.label :country
    22:             %br
    23:             = f.country_select(:country, priority_countries: ["US"])
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Also, can you put additional information such as error logs, and maybe the entire form could help as well.

Comment: @don_Bigote Do you have column named country in user model?

Comment: @don_Bigote Could you try this - `= f.country_select :country, {priority_countries: [ "US"], include_blank: "select country"}` ?

Comment: @don_Bigote Is it working?

Comment: could you show schema, controller and model please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the [issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select/issues/155) that I opened on GitHub.

Running `bundle update` and restarting the rails server solves the problem.

Comment: putting `gem 'country_select', '3.1.1'`  in your gemfile should work

Answer (score 2):

Hi As per the user [docs](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)

Because you are using with devise I am assuming you are using this on your user model, there for you must call `country_select("user", "country", priority_countries: ["US"])`

If your devise model is called something else, replace user with the model name